# Video capture using AVFoundation does not capture any audio

Tags: iphone, video, ios4, avfoundation

I'm using the following code to capture the movie file. Unfortunately it does not capture audio. Do I need route the microphone into my session as an additional input? I read somewhere that each session can only have one input? Just not sure how to go about this.

```
    // Create the session
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset =  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:[self backFacingCamera] error:nil];
audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:[self backFacingCamera] error:nil];
if(!input){
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create input!");
}
output= [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init] ;
[session addInput:input];
[session addOutput:output];
[session startRunning];
```

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specifically add audioInput as an input to your session. Also, your current code shows audioInput as pointing to the camera. It needs to point to an audio device. Something like:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

[[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[devices objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];
```